# which one is best for performance for my project, more columns or more rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a localization plugin for my cms. I have a few options to do this but the easiest is creating extra columns for each language (like title_en, content_en).

The other way is creating a column called 'language' and each language in each article I create a row. However dynamic areas are only 'title', 'content' and 'nice_url' but there are 10 columns (id, category, display, date ...) and these columns will be unnecessary.

The other ways (like creating extra table named article_translations) are not suitable for my CMS's plugin algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

More columns is not scaleable, and it's *much* easier to add rows than columns.

It is better to have a row for each language's data.

You haven't posted much information, but try to put all the common data into a one table and put the language-specific data in another child table with either an foreign key or an enum type for language. Use a foreign key to a language table if there is info about the language to want to store/retrieve. Use an enum instead if you want to check the value, or just use text if you are not fussy.

Also, it should be noted that you are unlikely to want more than one language at a time, so there wold be no advantage in having a hugely wide table where one row hold all information about all languages.

Comment: actually it is easy to implement my project, because If i use "more rows" way I have to create an extra column called owner_article and I have to check and update these rows every single request (like delete, update and edit)

Comment: Post some more info about what data you need to store. We can help you better if we know more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: There will be articles and each article will be in a few languages. Features that an article have will be in use in every translations.
If a were implementing this feature to my cms, it could be easy but it will be a plugin and If I use "more rows" way I have to change many things in the way that creating plugins, because it's not actually suitable for plugin feature.

Comment: in the long run you will be better off with well formed tables as suggested by Bohemian. I would go with putting the information that needs to be translated in a translation table that is linked to the master table by an id. one record per language with minimal duplication of data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is depends on how many languages are you planning support?
If several you can add several additional columns without any problems.
It will be easy to use this model for switching between languages. But if you are planning using many languages I think you should think about additional table(s).

Comment: A user generally use 4-5 languages and this means total 15 columns (title, content, nice_url). does it makes a problem?

Comment: Better to have a sub table that stores specific language translations, then. Then you have only as many records as there are translations, and you don't end up with table full of null/default records where there is no translation available.

Comment: No, it won't be a problem if you don't need searching by this table. Because table will be huge you will get big indexes and even for primary key if you use InnoDB